# Set up Twilio Client in a google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio

Would any one have a sample script or method how to setup Twilio Client to make and receive calls directly in a browser with Google apps script as a webapp or the like.

Here is how to initiate a Twilio call from GAS, but I can't seem to figure out how to do Twilio Client.

```
function makeCall() {

var to = "+1xxxxxxxxxx";
var from = "+1xxxxxxxxxx";

var callsUrl = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxx/Calls.json";
   
  var payload = {
    "To": to,
    "From" : from,
    "Twiml" : '<Response><Say>Hello this is a Twilio call</Say></Response>', 
    };
  
  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
      };
      
      options.headers = {    
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx") 
      };
      var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(callsUrl, options);
Logger.log(res);
    }
```

Comment: When you had got an error message, can you provide it? And, can you provide the official document of the method in API you want to use?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your response to try to help me (as you usually do) here is the documentation but it's for node.js and Express https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/browser-calls

Comment: Thank you for replying. I saw the URL you provided. But I cannot find the detail information for understanding the request in your Google Apps Script. I apologize for this. But, I would like to try to understand the specification of the API you want to use. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for checking into this. I would like to create a webapp in which I can make a browser call using Twilio Client. I don't know how to write the script for this in Googla apps script

Comment: I cannot be of help about Twilio API but maybe a look at the [Apps Script documentation for webapps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) may help